# Como eu faço o 3D funcionar no pyglet?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, 3d, pyopengl

Eu estava tentando criar utilizando OpenGL, Python e pyglet, um triangulo plano num espaço 3D, eu vi alguns tutoriais na internet, alguns vídeos no YouTube, e no fim eu escrevi esse código ai em baixo, o problema é que não funcionou como eu esperava, eu achava que se eu tentasse girar, daria para ver o triangulo plano girando, e quando afastasse o cenário o triangulo não tinha que diminuir?

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.gl import *

config = Config(sample_buffers=1, samples=8)
tela = pyglet.window.Window(height=500, width=500, config=config)

glViewport(0,0,500,500)
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
glLoadIdentity()
gluPerspective(35,1,0.1,1000)
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)

@tela.event
def on_draw():
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex3f(10,10,0)
    glVertex3f(100,10,0)
    glVertex3f(50,100,0)
    glEnd()
    glFlush()

@tela.event
def on_key_press(s,m):
    tela.clear()
    if s == pyglet.window.key.W:
        glTranslatef(0,0,1)
    if s == pyglet.window.key.S:
        glTranslatef(0,0,-1)
    if s == pyglet.window.key.A:
        glRotatef(1,0,1,0)
    if s == pyglet.window.key.D:
        glRotatef(-1,0,1,0)

pyglet.app.run()
```

Quando eu rodo o código aparece isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E quando eu tento girar o cenário isso acontece:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe onde eu estou errando?

Comment: adicione o código como texto, não como imagem. Desta forma fica mais fácil te ajudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi, o problema esta no pyglet, toda vez que a pagina atualiza ela passa pela função on_draw(), mas o problema é que o pyglet já define uma serie de coisas quando ele passa pela função para desenhar a tela, o que significa que mesmo que no inicio do código eu coloque os comandos:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
glLoadIdentity()
gluPerspective(35, 1, 0.1, 1000)
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
glLoadIdentity()
```

Simplesmente não vai funcionar, pois no primeiro momento em que a tela for redesenhada o pyglet vai transformar a imagem em 2D de novo(o que é uma merda), ou seja a solução é que eu tenho que colocar os códigos para definição de 3D dentro da função para redesenhar o triangulo, assim ele define o programa para 3D todas as vezes e o 3D passa a funcionar, eles só precisam ser incluídos antes que a função desenhe os objetos do cenário.

E a função `glViewport()` é inútil, ela só é útil quando eu mudo o tamanho da janela o que eu não fiz em nenhum momento então foi só um desperdício.